# Signing password and get value back

Tags: powershell, encryption, server, signing, windows-server-2016

We migrated one Windows Server 2008 to Server 2016.
Now I'm getting an error at this script:

```
cls
$key = (2,3,56,34,254,222,1,1,2,23,42,54,33,233,1,34,2,7,6,5,35,43,6,6,6,6,6,6,31,33,60,23)
$pass = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$securepass = $pass | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key
$bytes = [byte[]][char[]]$securepass            

$csp = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters
$csp.KeyContainerName = "SuperSecretProcessOnMachine"
$csp.Flags = $csp.Flags -bor [System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags]::UseMachineKeyStore
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider -ArgumentList 5120,$csp
$rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = $true

$encrypted = $rsa.Encrypt($bytes,$true)
$encrypted | Export-Clixml 'C:\Temp\encrypted_ysastaginpro_PRE.txt' -Force
```

Error Code:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Object already
exists."
At C:\Program Files\Staging\MESDI\Create_PSW_File_Poly.ps1:13 char:10
+ ...      $rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceP ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "Encrypt" with "2" argument(s): "Bad Length."
At C:\Program Files\Staging\MESDI\Create_PSW_File_Poly.ps1:18 char:3
+         $encrypted = $rsa.Encrypt($bytes,$true)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the the solution.
Run the PS Script as adminstrator.